# How to find the mins and maxs of an array of pixels in opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I'm working on a project that converts a graph into datapoints. I converted the image to grayscale and found the pixels that were only the graph from this:

```
pixels = np.argwhere(gray == 138)
```

I recreated the image to only represent the graph in black and white:

[image: here]

My issue now is how to deal with the np array. I converted it into a two row array, and I have between 10-30 y values for each x value. I need an algorithm to find out which is the 'right' y value. I've tried taking the avg of all y's, but the results aren't great. Most places where it is just a block of pixels, I want the max/min as the y value.

Comment: First try to come up with an algorithm without using any numpy trickery. First of all, since the origin of the graph is in bottom left corner of the image, it would be helpful to flip it around the horizontal axis. This way `y` axis goes in the same direction as `row` of the image. | Now, each column in the image corresponds to a different `x` value. So, iterate over columns. For each column, notice that there is a single continuous segment of white. So, for each column, find the first and last row containing a white pixel. Now it's your turn to interpret and map it to a set of x and y values.

Comment: I took your suggestions and reconfigured the array. I took the average of each column and got good results, but they're still not all that accurate. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Could you, please, edit your question, and update it to reflect the current state of your problem? Leave the existing stuff as is, just add more to the end. It would also be nice if you could state what you expect to get as the result (so that we know what to aim for).

Comment: However, I have a hunch a what's troubling you at this point, but IMHO it's not entirely trivial how to solve it. You really need some heuristic to select between min(y), avg(y) and max(y) for each column. You want to detect those very narrow peaks, and avoid suppressing them. So to start, look for columns that have long stretches of white. Look yourself at the sample image, find the places where your algorithm gives insufficient results, and consider how those scenarios could be handled better.

Comment: Thats exactly where I'm stuck. I think I just need to work more on those smaller peaks, I can get everything else pretty well.